# Can't import Cardboard SDK

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools, google-cardboard

There is a problem with importing Cardboard SDK to my project.

I downloaded [cardboard-java Github repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java)
then copied the files from it's library to my project's library folder and added the following dependencies:

```
 compile project(':libraries-common')

 compile project(':libraries-commonwidget')

 compile project(':libraries-videowidget')
```

But it gives error saying:

> Project with path ':libraries-common' could not be found in project
>   ':app'.

Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong, and tell me if there is another way of importing the SDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `project` syntax is used to describe a dependency on a separate [subproject](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) of your root Gradle project. Note that the example repository is [aware of all the library subprojects](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/blob/master/settings.gradle). You probably need to update your own `settings.gradle` to similarly be aware of the library subprojects you have copied into your Android Studio project.

Alternatively, start over and make sure you follow every step from this [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/get-started#using_android_studio) guide. In particular, using the **New module** import method should automatically update your `settings.gradle` file as you go:

> First, grab all the required .AAR files from the **libraries** folder of the sdk. To determine which .AARs you need to depend on, you can examine the **build.gradle** files of the various sample apps. For example, **samples/treasurehunt/build.gradle**'s dependency section has the following entries:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   compile project(':libraries-audio')
>   compile project(':libraries-common')
>   compile project(':libraries-core')
> }
> ```
>
> This indicates that an application similar to the Treasure Hunt sample needs the **audio**, **common**, and **core** libraries.
>
> Create new modules for each of these libraries. Using Android Studio's GUI, this can be done via **File -> New -> New Module...**. Select **Import .JAR/.AAR Package**. Locate one of the .AARs and import it.
>
> Then add this new module as a dependency to your main app via **File -> Project Structure -> Modules *(on the left side's section list)* -> YOUR APP's MODULE NAME -> Dependencies *(on the right side's tab list)* -> '+' -> Module Dependency**.